# filtering data by 7 different values in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to search by 1, or up to 7, different values. My data looks like this

```
{
        id: "123456",
        firstName: "john",
        lastName: "doe",
        middleName: "Leon",
        phone: "3216549878",
        dob: "10/12/1984",
        prefix: "Mr",
        suffix: "",
        gender: "male",
        ageClass: "adult",
        email: "john.doe@gmail.com",
        citizenship: "US",
        country: "US",
        state: "GA",
    }
```

and I'm trying to create a function that can filter data by phone, email, name(first and last), country, state, and id. However, all 7 fields may, or may not, be filtered at the same. For example, the user may want to search by phone and name, strictly just phone number, or only by email, or search by all 7 criteria.

I created the function but it's a 260-line if statement that is extremely hard to read and looks like a god-awful mess and that is why I'm trying to find a better way to do this.

**ANSWER - this is based on the correct answer i marked below but his code is slightly flawed.**

```
const filterParams = {
        firstName: fname,
        lastName: lname,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        country: country,
        state: state,
    };

const search = (objArray, filterParams) => {
    return objArray.filter((obj) => {
        return Object.keys(filterParams).every((key) =>
                obj[key].toLowerCase().includes(filterParams[key].toLowerCase())
            );
        });
    };
```

Comment: Does the presence of more fields to search by limit or expand the search criteria? For example if someone enters a `firstName`, and `id`, but the user who has that id does not have the same `firstName`, is the search supposed to return nothing or return both the user with the given id as well as all users with that same `firstName`?

Comment: just pass an array of callbacks as an argument and filter the data against them.

Comment: @smac89 if the id and name do not match then it would return nothing... every field that is searched, e.g. phone and firstname and lastname would be filtered. if other search criteria was empty it would be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an object with key value pair based on which you want to filter. For example if you want to filter entries that have first name Chris and last name Doe:

```
// filterParams = {firstName:"Chris", "lastName":"Doe"}

const search = (objArray, filterParams) => {
    return objArray.filter(obj => {  
        Object.keys(searchParams).every(key => searchParams[key] === obj[key]); 
    });
};
```

Comment: how would this work with filtering names that you're trying to a do a .include() with for example with names spelled differently, some may use Christopher instead of Chris, or Marrey instead Marry...so that someone can search "mar" for first name and "doe" for last name, and pull all results with first name that contains "Mar" and lastname of "doe"

Comment: I tried to make this work, but i noticed its actually not returning anything except for empty array, console logs inside the function show its working but none of the data actually gets returns

Comment: Your code if slightly flawed. After playing around with it i finally got it to work. And this seems to be the best answer and i will mark it correct, but i am going to post the updated version in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it fast and generic at the same time you should have only one loop over the array and have generic filter functions for your object.

There is a beautiful way to express is declaratively with functional programming.

```
import filter from "lodash/fp/filter";
import curry from 'lodash/fp/curry';

//1. Create generic filter function for your object schema
const eqStrictFirstName = (name) => filter((x) => x.firstName === name);
const hasPhone = (num) => filter(x => x.phone.includes(num));

//2. Make a generic function to combine those functions
//according to your business logic
const and = curry((predicates, item) => {
  return predicates.reduce((hasPassedSoFar, predicate) => hasPassedSoFar && predicate(item), true);
});

const array = [
  {
    id: "123456",
    firstName: "john",
    lastName: "doe",
    middleName: "Leon",
    phone: "3216549878",
    dob: "10/12/1984",
    prefix: "Mr",
    suffix: "",
    gender: "male",
    ageClass: "adult",
    email: "john.doe@gmail.com",
    citizenship: "US",
    country: "US",
    state: "GA"
  }
];

//3. Have fun combining them...
console.log(and([eqStrictFirstName("john"), hasPhone('21')], array));
```

Comment: Man, i was realy hoping this worked. It does work, just not how i intended. I noticed after i started adding filter functions for like the last name, and email, that whatever filter function is last in that "and" call, thats the filter it uses for the data, it wont check all data against each other. This is an otherwise beauitiful solution and easy to read, thank you and i wish i could mark it right